# How to custom formatter JFormattedTextField to display an IP address?

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

I have been trying to custom `JFormattedTextField` to display a mask for entering an IP address.

I read javadoc, and I tried with `###.###.###.###`, but it's not valid in many cases.

I found some article for this, they use Regex to format value but they don't display a mask for entering an IP.

I want to display 3 dots in text field to display IP address. Like this:

```
 .   .   .
```

I can input a IP Address in many cases. You can see in IPv4 configuration in Windows.

```
 .   .   .
```

Can you help me? Thanks for reading

Comment: `I read javadoc, and I tried with ###.###.###.###, but it's not valid in many cases.` maybe simple mistake, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)  demonstraded your issue with [InputMask and Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Comment: +1 for adding the [tag:homework] tag.

Comment: Most likely `MaskFormatter` isn't flexible enough to give satisfactory behavior. Do you _need_ to use `MaskFormatter` or was it just what you happened to try?

Answer (score 2):

I know this won't help you with your homework, but for other people looking for a solution: Jidesoft Grids (I am not affiliated) has a class for this: [com.jidesoft.field.IPTextField](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/field/IPTextField.html).

Generally, I think it will be difficult to achieve a satisfactory solution with JFormattedTextField.

Answer (score 2):

You could try four `JFormattedTextField` in a row, each separated by a `JLabel(".")`. With the dot out of the way, that might make the number format easier to get right.