# Mask the IP Address when the user enters in text field Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

I have a JTextField to accommodate an ip address with 3 dots. 
255.120.320.123. When the user enters this IP address, I want to mask it like ***.***.***.***
I was referring this thread, [How to custom formatter JFormattedTextField to display an IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105639/how-to-custom-formatter-jformattedtextfield-to-display-an-ip-address)

`jFormattedTextField` did not work for me. Can anyone give me an example with `jFormattedTextField` with 3 dots visible?

Or do I need to use 4 `jFomattedTextField`/`JPasswordField` as mentioned in this thread?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need to use [`MaskFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#maskformatter) ,for example:

```
try {
    MaskFormatter mf = new MaskFormatter("###.###.###.###");
    JFormattedTextField f = new JFormattedTextField(mf);
    add(f);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume your trying to use JFormattedTextField? Maybe you should combine it with MaskFormatter.

Something like:
      // IPv4 like 192.168.1.1

```
   MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("###.###.###.###");
 JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
```

[Here is an Example and guide](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48584.html)

Comment: while entering ip address 255.255.123.122 in the textfield,these values are visible. I wanted to mask it like if i use the JPasswordField instead of showing it as 255.255.123.122 in GUI, wanted to show as ***.***.***.***   I am referring this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339702/is-there-an-alternative-to-jpasswordfield

Comment: @user1631072 Oh I see, that is a tad different. Swap out the JFormattedTextField for a [JPasswordField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html) (and use echo char etc). I believe you can still use a MaskFormatter with one of those (maybe...)

Comment: Hi Nathan, Thank you for your reply. Is there a way to use JPasswordField? The problem I am facing is, currently in a textfield displaying 3spaces.3spaces.3spaces.3spaces to enter the ip address. when I use the echochar with JPasswordField it takes space and . to * . So I am getting like  *********** instead of ***.***.***.*** Once I select the checkbox mask, it is masking the spaces and dot. Before the user enters the ip address, echochar masking the spaces and dot to * .

Comment: You may have to go back JFormattedTextField and have the chars you want converted to * by using ActionListener or KeyListener. I'll have a look into this if i have time.

Comment: char[] pass = tf1.getPassword();
    tf1.setEchoChar('*');
    for(int i =0;i<pass.length;i++) {
    if(pass[i] == '.' ){
    tf1.setEchoChar('.');
    } 
   }  I tried this in the actionPerformed, But it sets the echoChar as dot(.). It sets the echo char which is set at last.