# javafx textfield ip address

Tags: java, javafx, ip, textfield, ipv4

I would like to make sure the user enter a valid IPv4 address in a JavaFX TextField (0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255) but i can't seems to find any valid solutions.

I tried with that code :

```
    private final TextField serverURI = new TextField();
    final UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> urlFilter = new UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change>() {
        @Override
        public TextFormatter.Change apply(TextFormatter.Change change) {
            final String text = change.getText();
            return (text.isEmpty() || text.matches("^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$")) ? change : null;
        }
    };
    final TextFormatter<String> urlFormatter = new TextFormatter(urlFilter);
    serverURI.setTextFormatter(urlFormatter);
```

But I can't even type one digit... It seems to work with only one input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are tricky.

The first note is that you are using `change.getText()`, which gives the text being added or removed; you want to test the resulting text (i.e. the text after adding or deleting). For this, use `change.getControlNewText()`.

For example, if the current text in the text field is `"255.2"`, and the user types a `"5"`, then `change.getText()` will return `"5"`, whereas `change.getControlNewText()` will return `"255.25"`.

This still leaves the main issue, which is that the filter is being applied to every individual change to the text, and you are testing for a complete ip address. So, for example, to type "255.255.255.255", the user would first type "2". You test (even with `change.getControlNewText()`) if "2" matches your regular expression, it fails (because it's not a complete IP address), and so the change is vetoed. On the next key typed, `change.getControlNewText()` will be `"25"`, and so on. So you want the entire sequence `"2`", `"25"`, `"255"`, `"255."`, `"255.2"`, etc, etc to pass your filter. You also need the filter to accept the user deleting characters, copying and pasting, and so on.

So you really need a regex that tests for partial entries, instead of complete entries, which is of course a little trickier to get right. The following is an example, not intended to be bullet-proof, but should get you on the right track (at least). Note that you probably want additional validation when the user commits the value, to check you have a complete, valid ip address.

```
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter.Change;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class IPTextFieldTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField ipTextField = new TextField();
        String regex = makePartialIPRegex();
        final UnaryOperator<Change> ipAddressFilter = c -> {
            String text = c.getControlNewText();
            if  (text.matches(regex)) {
                return c ;
            } else {
                return null ;
            }
        };
        ipTextField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(ipAddressFilter));
        StackPane root = new StackPane(ipTextField);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 120);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private String makePartialIPRegex() {
        String partialBlock = "(([01]?[0-9]{0,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))" ;
        String subsequentPartialBlock = "(\\."+partialBlock+")" ;
        String ipAddress = partialBlock+"?"+subsequentPartialBlock+"{0,3}";
        return "^"+ipAddress ;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine ! But I don't understand why it works with your regex and not mine even if I use getControlNewText() instead of getText()
I just have to figure out how to make sure the user enter something between two dots and maybe prevent to put zero in front :)

Comment: Because `"2"`, `"25"`, `"255"`, `"255."`, `"255.2"`, etc etc do not match your regex. It is checking every time the text changes.

Comment: Edited answer to clarify that last point. Please accept the answer as correct if it answers your question.

Comment: One last note: I would not try to avoid leading zeros. For example, if a user had accidentally typed `200` instead of `100`, and you did not allow `00` in any block, it would make it unreasonably hard for them to edit it.

Comment: It will return true if you enter only a dot.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually check the numbers.

```
private static boolean checkIfValidIpv4(String text){
   StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text,".");
   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){ 
     if(!st.hasMoreTokens()){
       return false;
     }
     int num = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
     if(num < 0 || num > 255){
       return false;
    }
   }
   if(st.hasMoreTokens()){
     return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

It's not elegant but it works.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't prevent the user to type anything but digits. I would like something in real time :)

Comment: oh... if that's the case, I can't help you :)
But you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040845/mask-the-ip-address-when-the-user-enters-in-text-field-java-swing) question... it's sort of similar. @Phoste